# How to set Innodb Buffer Pool Size

Tags: mysql, innodb, my.cnf, configuration, buffer-pool

I have a database using innodb completely. Its now having a `innodb_buffer_pool_size` at **128MB**. Which I know is very less for my user.

But no matter what I do it won't change. I have added a value of **1G** both in `/etc/my.cnf`
and also in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and restarted the mysql service. It doesn't seem to update.

My mysql keeps on stopping and when i run `mysqltuner` & `tuning-primer.sh` all point to the fact I have to increase the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` but it simply won't increase.

Is there any other way to enforce this?

Comment: How did you identify your current buffer pool size?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the values to a new `my.cnf` file inside, `/etc/mysql/conf.d` solved the issue. Added only the value we wanted to override. For some reason, values added elsewhere were ignored by mysql.

**Note:**
Make sure `/etc/mysql/conf.d` is included in `my.cnf` file located at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.
It included by default.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are adding `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and it's value in `mysqld` section of `my.cnf` file of a MySQL server you would like to change.